# Getting Cross-Origin Request Blocked while making POST reqquest to API using [MEAN]

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, cors

I am working with `ngx-tags-input` in my form which allows me to add `tags`. I'm quite surprised because I am already using `cors`. See.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5"
    ...
  }
```

**server.js**

```
const cors = require('cors');
...
app.use(cors());
```

Here is my simple form
**ask.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row pt-5">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 bg-light">
      <form [formGroup]="editorForm (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <!-- some other input field -->
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <ngx-tags-input class="form-control input-lg" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="makeNewQuest.tags" id="my-tags" name="tags"></ngx-tags-input>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3 mb-3" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
      </form>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using `(keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()"` to prevent form submit on enter key because tags are separated by enter key. Instead, my form gets submitted on `click` event on button.

Here is my `ts` file for the same component

```
onSubmit() {
    console.log("clicked onSubmit");        
    var titleFromField = "Demo title";
    var content = "Demo content";
    var askedby = localStorage.getItem('firstname') + " " + localStorage.getItem('lastname');
    var date = new Date().toUTCString();

    this.makeNewQuest.qtitle = titleFromField;
    this.makeNewQuest.qcontent = content;
    this.makeNewQuest.date = date;
    this.makeNewQuest.askedby = askedby;

    console.log(this.makeNewQuest);


    this._auth.pushNewQuest(this.makeNewQuest)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          //console.log(res);
          this._router.navigate(['/discussions']);
        },
        err => console.log(err)
      );
  }
```

Everything looks good but data is not pushed to `mongodb`. I'm getting `cors` error.

[image: This is what my console looks like]

PS: I have uploaded some important file on [github](https://github.com/tmtanzeel/temporary)

Comment: Can you paste your server side code?

Comment: Ok. I have uploaded all the necessary files on github. https://github.com/tmtanzeel/temporary

Comment: Is server side code and front-end code both running on localhost:3000? If yes then please change the port of one server and try.

Answer (score -1):

This Error occurs as your app is not running on the same domain as your service. You need to configure your Server to accept those calls by adding the ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ Header.

Comment: Please read the question once again and edit your answer accordingly before you get a down vote. All the best.